# Start DbSchema with Oracle JDK

Tags: java, db-schema

I'm trying to use the software `DbSchema`.
I found different bugs using ***java-8-openjdk-amd64***,
 but with ***oracle-java8-jdk-amd64*** no one.

However, I develop with **openjdk** and I would use **Oracle** only with DbSchema start, that's possible?

---

I'm trying to fix with this option:

> INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8-jdk-amd64/jre/bin

in the sh script located `/usr/local/bin/DbSchema`, but it doesn't works.

---

Another way is config the **update-alternatives**:

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

0. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java  *
1. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
2. /usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8-jdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

I can select the third alternative (Oracle) and launch DbSchema, but this solution doesn't work with me because I usually need to work with the openjdk.

Other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I have a compromise:

1. I select the OracleJdk like default with update-alternatives of Java
   and start DbSchema without a problem.
2. When I develop my projects I choose the openJdk with my IDE.